# Group by functionality in Java

Tags: java, string, collections

I am trying to write a Java program that loads the data (from a tab delimited DAT file) and determines the average amount in Euros (EUR), grouped by Country and Credit Rating.

I have 2 questions,

1. what is the best way to load the data into data structure after spliting into array?
2. How do i approach about providing group by functionality in Java

---

**Update:** I have given a first try and this is how implementation looks like. Feels like there is a room for improvement.

```
    /**
 * @param rows - Each row as a bean
 * This method will group objects together based on Country/City and Credit Rating
 */
static void groupObjectsTogether(List<CompanyData> rows) {
    Map<String, List<CompanyData>> map = new HashMap<String, List<CompanyData>>();

    for(CompanyData companyData : rows){
        String key;

        if(companyData.getCountry().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("") || companyData.getCountry() == null){
            key = companyData.getCity()+":"+companyData.getCreditRating();          //use city+creditRating as key
        }else{
            key = companyData.getCountry()+":"+companyData.getCreditRating();       //use country+creditRating as key
        }

        if(map.get(key) == null){
            map.put(key, new ArrayList<CompanyData>());
        }
        map.get(key).add(companyData);
    }

    processGroupedRowsAndPrint(map);
}
```

Comment: Can you use a database (like HSQL) or does it have to be all Java?

Comment: how your data structure lookslike? do you have one dimensional array with cells or two dimensional array withs rows and cells?

Comment: I can not use a database and need to make suer i follow best coding practice. For eg. I need to make use of BigDecimal for currency precision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It all depends on the amount of data and performance (CPU vs memory) of the machine. It the amount of data is not significant (less than millions of records or columns) and the number of columns is fixed then you may simply put all data in arrays using

```
String[] row = String.split(";");
```

which shall split each row using ; as delimiter. Then you may achieve your grouping functionality using HashMap, i.e.:

```
ArrayList<String[]> rowAr = new ArrayList<String[]>();
HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>();
int index = 0;
for (String rowStr: rows) {
    String[] row = rowStr.split(";");
    rowAr.add(row);
    String companyCode = row[0];
    //please keep in mind that for simplicity of the example I avoided
    //creation of new array if it does not exist in HashMap
    ((ArrayList<Integer>)map.get(companyCode)).add(index);
    index++;
}
```

Sorry for any syntax or other simple errors above (I do not have any tools in hand to verify if there is not any stupid mistake).